# How can I use custom SVG icon inside Vuetify v-icon component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I know I can use predefined material design (or font awesome etc...) icons in Vuetify like this:

```
<v-icon>mdi-clock</v-icon>
```

But is there a way to use `v-icon` component to display my custom icon defined as svg in `my-icon.svg` file? This .svg file is located located in my project `public/img` directory but how can I reference it inside `v-icon` component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Add Custom SVG Icon in Vuetify - Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614557/how-to-add-custom-svg-icon-in-vuetify-vue)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563938/1981247

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK If you want to use as external svg, the answer is unfortunately no.

Anyway, you can import the svg file as a component with [vue-svg-loader](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader) then use inside `v-icon`.

```js
import Stack from "@/icons/stack.svg"; // import /src/icons/stack.svg

export default {
  components: {
    Stack
  }
};
```

Then use it

```html
<v-icon>
  <Stack/>
</v-icon>
```

Another solution [How To Add Custom SVG Icon in Vuetify - Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614557/how-to-add-custom-svg-icon-in-vuetify-vue).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same using CSS.

```
.v-icon
  height 20px
  width 20px
  &.engine
    background-image url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/9344/train.svg)
    background-size contain
    background-repeat no-repeat
  &::before
    visibility hidden
    content ""
```

check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tt-hars/pen/BaybBQV).