# How to properly import component in nuxt.config.js to use as a custom icon?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use an SVG file as a custom icon, using this structure in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
import UploadIcon from '@/components/icons/UploadIcon'

export default {
...
    vuetify: {
       customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
       icons: {
           values: {
              upload: {
                  component: UploadIcon  <------here is my custom icon
              }
           }
       }
    }
 },
```

Nuxt is showing error:

```
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                          │
   │                                                                               │
   │   Error: Cannot find module '@/components/icons/UploadIcon'                   │
   │   Require stack:                                                              │
   │   - C:\Users\Admin\Documents\portfolio\artwork\artwork\nuxt.config.js         │
```

The thing is that IDE automatically does such import:
`import UploadIcon from '@/components/icons/UploadIcon'`

And it doesn't work.
What I tried:

1. doing `~` instead of `@` in path to component.
2. other variations of path, including absolute path.

However, when I try to use absolute path it shows such an error:

```
   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                  │
   │                                       │
   │   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯
```

So I can't find a way, I checked these documentations:

- https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets
- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/

Generally I've been trying to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563938/7017890
but there is a regular `vuetify.js` config file being used. With Nuxt it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would suggest using `vuetify.options.js` config file instead of loading configurations from `nuxt.config.js` ([@nuxtjs/vuetify documentation](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#optionspath)).

in your `vuetify.options.js` file (*keep it in the top-level dir*)

```js
// Note the lack of a leading slash (/)
import myCustomIcon from "components/icons/UploadIcon";

export default function () {
  return {
    // other vuetify options here,
    icons: {
      values: {
        upload: { component: myCustomIcon }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't even think about using an external `vuetify.options.js` file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Avraham's solution above is correct.

In addition, if you're using the vuetify template in Nuxt, you can use it like this:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clipped: false,
      drawer: false,
      fixed: false,
      items: [
        {
          icon: "$myCustomIcon_1",
          title: "TitleText_1",
          to: "/",
        },
        {
          icon: "$myCustomIcon_2",
          title: "TitleText_2",
          to: "/",
        },
        {
          icon: "$myCustomIcon_3",
          title: "TitleText_3",
          to: "/",
        },
        {
          icon: "$myCustomIcon_4",
          title: "TitleText_4",
          to: "/",
        },
      ],
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

and then the proper syntax to use in the v-list for loop is the following:

```js
<v-list-item-action>
   <v-icon size="30">{{ `${item.icon}` }}</v-icon>
</v-list-item-action>
```