# Add Custom icon to ":append-icon="value ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye'" at v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

code

```
         <v-text-field
            class="boxtext"
            :label="$t('Password')"
            :append-icon="value ? 'mdi-eye-off' : 'mdi-eye'"
            @click:append="() => (value = !value)"
            :type="value ? 'password' : 'text'"
            @keyup.enter="login"
            v-model="input.password"
            filled
            dense
            outlined
          />
```

Is There a way to add custom icon in this code.
my custom icon is in "../assets/xxxx.svg"

Update######

Found solution by this link [How To Add Custom SVG Icon in Vuetify - Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614557/how-to-add-custom-svg-icon-in-vuetify-vue)