# How use Feather Icons in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i am trying to integrate Feather icons in vuetify. Has anyone integrated any third party icon sets?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not done this but Vuetify provides a way for achieving that. See more here: [Using custom icons docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#using-custom-icons). Also, this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614557/how-to-add-custom-svg-icon-in-vuetify-vue).

> You can import and assign an svg to an icon value. The imported svg
> should contain only the path without the `<svg>` wrapper.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import myIconSvg from 'myIcon.svg'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
    values: {
      customIconSvg: myIconSvg,
      customIconSvgPath: 'M14.989,9.491L6.071,0.537C5.78,0.246,5.308,0.244,5.017,0.535c-0.294,0.29-0.294,0.763-0.003,1.054l8.394,8.428L5.014,18.41c-0.291,0.291-0.291,0.763,0,1.054c0.146,0.146,0.335,0.218,0.527,0.218c0.19,0,0.382-0.073,0.527-0.218l8.918-8.919C15.277,10.254,15.277,9.784,14.989,9.491z',
    },
  },
})
```