# Is it possible to use my .svg icons in vue3 and vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vueify

I have several images or icons (.svg) and I would like to know what is the best way to use my svg as vuetify icons.

Comment: I think it does support the custom icons: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#creating-a-custom-icon-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to manage and show ***SVG*** icons into ***Vue*** projects

1. if you have many ***SVG*** files , you can use  ***icomoon*** and import all ***SVG*** and manage them.
   this [link](https://medium.com/@jessdelisio/icon-fonts-how-to-create-your-own-with-icomoon-a1c92976b9c2) can help you . if you have any problem with this package, I can help you.
2. you can implement a ***Vue*** component and import a ***SVG*** into that and you can change styles, etc to that component but it is useful if you have a few ***SVG*** images. this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/managing-svg-icons-in-vuejs-applications-7f5c9e7b6ffa) can help you.
3. you can add it into ***Vuetify*** and then use it. look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614557/how-to-add-custom-svg-icon-in-vuetify-vue) please
4. you can add inline ***SVG*** into all pages you want.

I guess the first and third ways are suitable for your cause as you said, you have several ***SVG***

Comment: I think the third option is the most suitable one for OP's situation.

Comment: yeah but sometimes developers need to reduce the project size , in that case developer need to import all svg into icomoon and implement the package and then they inject that ( JSON file ) file into project .